# CSS Vertical Menu with Nested Lists, Need jQuery Delay on MouseOut

Tags: jquery

I'm new with jQuery and I'm trying to solve an issue with my navigation. I built a vertical menu with many nested lists. It's purely CSS but my client requested that the sub menu currently open stays open for a second or so when you're no longer hovering over it.

Here's the site I'm working on: http://dev.musgraveagencies.com/

And here is the site they currently have, and how they want the menu to delay: http://www.musgraveagencies.com/

I believe I can use jQuery to achieve this, but I want the site to work as is if Javascript isn't enabled.

**Edit:** Thanks for everyone's help! Here is the final code below.

My HTML:

```
<body class="nojs">
        <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Development Projects</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Design Build</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Interior Design</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Project Example</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Project Example 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Project Example 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Project Example 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Industrial</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Project Example 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Project Example 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Project Example 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Project Example 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Residential</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Neighbourhood</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
#nav {
    width: 156px;
    font: 9pt 'TeXGyreScholaRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}

#nav ul a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 19pt;
    text-indent: 2px;
}

#nav ul a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
    background: #484848;
}

#nav ul {
    width: 156px;
}

#nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 156px;
    top: 0;
    left: 156px;
}

body.nojs #nav ul li ul  {
    display: none;
}

body.nojs #nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav ul li ul').hide();
        $('body').removeClass('nojs');

        var config = {    
            sensitivity: 2, 
            interval: 200,    
            timeout: 700, 
        };

        var animating = false;

        $('#nav ul li').hoverIntent(
        function () {
                animating = true;
                $('> ul', this).fadeIn(100, function() {
                    animating = false;
                });
        },

        function () {
            animating = true;
            $('> ul', this).delay(400).fadeOut(200, function() {
                animating = false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: there are numerous menu plugins... easier than reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is, you are triggering a transition (fade) with jQuery but hiding the element immediately with your CSS. So this happens with no delay.

You can use the `transition-delay` or `animation-delay` properties with CSS3 but these are not supported in IE. All others support them but not with most versions.

```
transition-delay: 2s;
-moz-transition-delay: 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition-delay: 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition-delay: 2s; /* Opera */
```

So, I think you should migrate most of the CSS (hover pseudo-classes) to javascript/jQuery and hide/show with delay using the `setTimeout()` method or jQuery's `delay()` method.

**UPDATE:**

Since you are concerned if javascript is not enabled in the user's browser; without javascript and CSS delay related properties, I don't think it is possible to delay a change on an HTML element's appearance.

So what you can do is;

1. Create a CSS only version of the menu (with using transition-delay and/or animation-delay CSS3 properties if you want the delay). If these properties are not supported on the browser, only down-side is you won't get the "delay", but your menu will still work.
2. Create a javascript version of the menu (with setTimeout etc methods for delay).
3. Use the `<noscript>` tags for non-javascript content and your CSS-only menu and place them inside it.

This way you will have both users satisfied.

Comment: I'm worried about how the navigation will function if Javascript isn't enabled, so I was hoping to find a way to do this without using hide and show in jQuery. Thanks for showing me transition-delay though!

Comment: @Dynerseft, You said in your question: "I can't get the jQuery above to work". So we are answering that. "What if javascript is not enabled in the browser" is another question. If you target a general audience, javascript will probably be on. Most of the modern (client) web-applications depend on JS. Anyway, without JS, your best bet (for delay) is explained in my answer: CSS transition-delay

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on adding a "nojQuery" class that gets removed if Javascript is enabled so I can have it working both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jQuery HoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

You can see it in use @ thecl.com, it also helps an issue in ie8/7 with not being able to go from the parent anchor to the sub-nav.

Comment: Thanks, neat little plugin.

Answer (score 1):

try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hamidlab/adadv/

I have removed all top-level and sub-level classes, and used `>` to target direct child.

Have done a little changes in js also (You don't need js, if you don't care about the fadeIn effect)

```
$('#nav ul li').hover(function(){
    $(' > ul', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn();  
}, function(){
    $(' > ul', this).hide(0);
});
```

Some Changes in CSS : http://jsfiddle.net/hamidlab/adadv/1/

Note : 
For this small thing you don't need a plugin. 
I feel its better not to use plugin and keep things simple and clean when you can.